# Showing related Div onclick/Hover of image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to combine hover/click in jquery so that the div below an image shows on both click and hover. I'm by no means an expert in Jquery hence the struggle. I posted previously but have since deleted, apologies for the rubbisg question.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/40k95gjc/19/) which gives the general idea of what i'm trying to do - Second Attempt.

```
<div class="timeline-pills">
    <div class='timeline-element col-md-2' id='service-1'>
        <img onmouseover="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/advisory-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/advisory.png';" src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/advisory.png" alt="advisory" width="20%"><h2>Advisory</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-element col-md-2' id='service-2'>
        <img onmouseover="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/tbli-weekly-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/tbli-weekly.png';" src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/tbli-weekly.png" alt="tbli weekly" width="20%"><h2>TBLI WEEKLY</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-element col-md-2' id='service-3'>
        <img onmouseover="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/events-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/events.png';" src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/events.png" alt="events" width="20%"><h2>EVENTS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-element col-md-2' id='service-4'>
        <img onmouseover="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/foundation-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/foundation.png';" src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/foundation.png" alt="tbli foundation" width="20%"><h2>FOUNDATION</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-element col-md-2' id='service-5'>
        <img onmouseover="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/capital-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/capital.png';" src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/capital.png" alt="advisory" width="20%"><h2>CAPITAL CONNECT</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='timeline-info-panels'>
    <div class='timeline-info ' id='1'>
        <h3>TBLI Consulting & Advisory offers:</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-info' id='2'>
        <h3>TBLI WEEKLY</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-info' id='3'>
        <h3>EVENTS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-info' id='4'>
        <h3>FOUNDATION</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='timeline-info' id='5'>
        <h3>TBLI CAPITAL CONNECT</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The below is some code I've found and adapted slighty:

```
$('.timeline-info-panels').hide();
$('.timeline-info').hide();

$('.timeline-element').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover-over-time-pill');
  $('.timeline-info-panels').show();

  var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
  var newID = hoverID.replace('service-', '');
  $('#' + newID).show();
});

$('.timeline-element').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover-over-time-pill');
  $('.timeline-info-panels .timeline-info').hide();

  var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
  var newID = hoverID.replace('service-', '');
  $('#' + newID).hide();
});

$('.timeline-element').click(function() {

  var deActive = $(this).hasClass('active');

  // Removes old active elements for second click
  $('.timeline-element.active,.timeline-info.active').removeClass('active');

  // If clicked element is not active, activate it.
  if (deActive == false) {
    var hoverID = $(this).attr("id");
    var newID = hoverID.replace('service-', '');

    // Set active
    $('#' + newID).addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

What I'm stuck on:

1. Making the Advisory text/content to display on page load
2. When hovering the previous text does not disappear, it only disappears on click.

Apologies for my previous attempt at this question.

Any pointers or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Donna

Comment: *When hovering the previous text does not disappear, it only disappears on click* - unclear what you *do* want it to do.  Seems there's 3 options:  1) if click = stick, so hover on another = do nothing as first remains 2) hover un-sticks, so hover on 2nd is the same as clicking again on 1st then continues as if no click was made 3) hover temp replace click-stick, so on mouseleave, restore previous click.   (1) is easiest as you just check for `$(".timeline-info.active")`.  (2) is also easy as you just remove active from timeline-info.active on mouseenter.   (3) would need to remember which

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet.

```js
$(document)
  .on("mouseenter", ".timeline-pills .timeline-element", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentElement = $(this);
    const dataTarget = currentElement.data("target");
    const dataTargetElem = $("div.timeline-info#" + dataTarget);

    $(".timeline-pills .timeline-element").removeClass("hover-pill");
    currentElement.addClass("hover-pill");

    $(".timeline-info").hide();
    dataTargetElem.show();
  })
  .on("mouseleave", ".timeline-pills .timeline-element", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const activeElement = $(".timeline-pills .timeline-element.active");
    const dataTarget = activeElement.data("target");
    const dataTargetElem = $("div.timeline-info#" + dataTarget);

    $(".timeline-pills .timeline-element").removeClass("hover-pill");

    $(".timeline-info").hide();
    dataTargetElem.show();
  })
  .on("click", ".timeline-pills .timeline-element", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentElement = $(this);
    const dataTarget = currentElement.data("target");

    const dataTargetElem = $("div.timeline-info#" + dataTarget);
    $(".timeline-pills .timeline-element").removeClass("active");
    currentElement.addClass("active");

    $(".timeline-info").hide();
    dataTargetElem.show();
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f0f0f1;
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline-pills {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.timeline-pills .timeline-element {
  background: #dcdcde;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
  color: #50575e;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timeline-pills .timeline-element h2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: inherit;
}

.timeline-pills .timeline-element img {
  width: 30px;
}

.timeline-pills .timeline-element.active,
.timeline-pills .timeline-element.hover-pill {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #0a95ff;
}

.timeline-info-panels {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.timeline-info-panels .timeline-info {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.timeline-info-panels .timeline-info.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline-pills">
  <div class="timeline-element active" data-target="service-1">
    <img src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/advisory.png" alt="advisory" />
    <h2>Advisory</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-element" data-target="service-2">
    <img src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/tbli-weekly.png" alt="tbli weekly" />
    <h2>TBLI WEEKLY</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-element" data-target="service-3">
    <img src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/events.png" alt="events" />
    <h2>EVENTS</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-element" data-target="service-4">
    <img src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/foundation.png" alt="tbli foundation" />
    <h2>FOUNDATION</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-element" data-target="service-5">
    <img src="https://tbli.sitewidedesign.co.uk/images/services/capital.png" alt="advisory" />
    <h2>CAPITAL CONNECT</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-info-panels">
  <div class="timeline-info active" id="service-1">
    <h3>TBLI Consulting & Advisory offers:</h3>
    <p>
      Sustainable & Social Capital Strategies – Formation & Funding Strategies
      <br /> Permanent Capital Strategies & Platform Connectivity (public/private markets) <br /> Market Intelligence & Forensic Due Diligence<br /> Direct access to TBLI network of investors through TBLI’s Capital Connect investor database.<br /> OCIO
      Models (Outsourced Officer/Advisor) Advisory & Engagement<br /> Investor Relations – Communications & Reporting; Compliance<br />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-info" id="service-2">
    <h3>TBLI WEEKLY</h3>
    <p>
      A weekly newsletter curated by TBLI featuring all the most important Impact Investing/ESG news combined with all the upcoming TBLI events & announcements.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-info" id="service-3">
    <h3>EVENTS</h3>
    <p>
      TBLI has a plethora of experience hosting events and curating programmes, having organised conferences focussing on educating investors on the importance of impact investing for over 25 years. Since the outbreak of the pandemic, we have shifted focus
      to virtual events after doing annual conferences on a regular basis, this has allowed us to increase our reach and allowed more investors to get access to our content and the investment opportunities in our network. We will continue to focus on
      virtual events. If you are interested in engaging or hiring TBLI to organise and curate an in-person or an online event for you, you can contact us.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-info" id="service-4">
    <h3>FOUNDATION</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut ero labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.Lorem ipsum dolor sit Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
      ullamco.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-info" id="service-5">
    <h3>TBLI CAPITAL CONNECT</h3>
    <p>
      TBLI Capital Connect is our matchmaking system where we connect funds and projects to our network of investment allocators. The algorithm matches investors to investment opportunities according to the their investment profile and vice versa. Funds & companies
      looking to raise funds will be able to be connected to impact investors that invest regularly in their industry. A very efficient way of fundraising.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll take over to a fiddle and see if i can edit for my exact requirements, I really appreciate your help.